# Cannot Inject HttpConfigService in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to set up an async config class for the HTTP Module as described in the documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module#async-configuration.

```
@Injectable()
class HttpConfigService implements HttpModuleOptionsFactory {
  constructor() {}
  createHttpOptions(): HttpModuleOptions {
    return {
      timeout: 5000,
      maxRedirects: 5,
     };
  }
}
```

Then in my module:

```
imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(), HttpConfigService, HttpModule.registerAsync({
        useClass: HttpConfigService,
    })
],
```

Despite trying to copy the pattern in the documentation, I get the following error:

```
Module '"./httpconfig.service"' declares 'HttpConfigService' locally, but it is not exported.ts(2459)
```

It seems like my custom `HttpConfigService` isn't getting injected properly. Would could be the cause of this? Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `export` to the class definition.

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigService implements HttpModuleOptionsFactory {
  constructor() {}
  createHttpOptions(): HttpModuleOptions {
    return {
      timeout: 5000,
      maxRedirects: 5,
     };
  }
}
```